# check if key exists in object in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, push, each

I have a developed below code,

```
var list = [];
// read data from api

$.each(data.samples, function(k, v) {
  if (!list.hasOwnProperty(v.key) 
    list.push({
      'key': v.key,
      'title': v.title.
      'sent': false
    }); 

console.log(list);
```

Updated(Sample Data From API)

```
var obj ={
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 4,
    "samples": [
        {
            "key": "s-111",
            "title": {
                "summary": "title 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "s-112",
            "title": {
                "summary": "title 2"
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "s-113",
            "title": {
                "summary": "title 3"
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "s-114",
            "title": {
                "summary": "title 3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And some necessary nested key,value which i don't need it as well.
however I just need to check if new key does not exists add new key to my list while API update every 2 minutes

Comment: Can you provide sample data from the API?

Comment: What is Question? What is expected result of `!list.hasOwnProperty(v.key)` called on array `list`?

Comment: typo - you should have a comma after title eg: title: v.title. should be title: v.title,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is you are checking property of object instead of value of object, where `v.key` is not set as a property of any of the objects pushed to `list` array.

You can use `.some()` to iterate objects in array to check if any objects in array have `v.key` value by returning `o.key === v.key`, as `v.key` is set as *value* of `"key"` property of objects pushed to array.

```js
var obj = {
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 4,
  "samples": [{
      "key": "s-111",
      "title": {
        "summary": "title 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "s-112",
      "title": {
        "summary": "title 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "s-113",
      "title": {
        "summary": "title 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "s-114",
      "title": {
        "summary": "title 3"
      }
    },
    // duplicate entry to exclude
    {
      "key": "s-114",
      "title": {
        "summary": "title 3"
      }
    }
  ]
}

var list = [];
// read data from api

$.each(obj.samples, function(k, v) {
  if (!list.some(function(o) {
      return o.key === v.key
    }))
    list.push({
      "key": v.key,
      "title": v.title,
      "sent": false
    });
});

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just something else, how can i remove from list by key s-114 @guest271314

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.findIndex()` to get the index of object in array where value of `"key"` property is `"s-114"`. Call `.splice()` on array with index and `1` as parameters, or call `delete` on array specifying index to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is that you're asking but from what I understand, what you want to do is add the object to your list if a key from `data.samples` is not already present in the list?

In the above case what you would want to do is something like this:

```
var list = [];
// read data from API

// Note Key, Value change
$.each(data.samples, function(key, value) {
    if (!list.includes(key)) {
        list.push({
            'key': v.key,
            title: v.title,
            'sent': false
        }); 
    }
}
console.log(list);
```

As I don't have an environment to test this right now I can't tell you if this will work for your purpose.

However, if you are attempting to add based on the *key* not being in the list you will want to use the `key` *parameter*, (**not** the `v.key` value of the parameter) as per the [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

And while you can use the `hasOwnProperty(...)` method I would recommend you to use the `includes(...)` method which is more specific to arrays. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Again, you may have to do some extra troubleshooting and cajoling to get this to work for your specific application.

Good luck && Hope this helps!

Comment: Note, `list` would be an array of objects.